# uint64_t string conversion and extraction of first 4 characters

Tags: c

I've been handed this function that checks if a given 4 digit PIN number is correct. This PIN is a string of length 5 (e.g. "1234\0"). The real PIN is obtained after some calculations, by converting a uint64_t to string and extracting the first 4 characters:

```
uint8_t pin_verification(uint64_t number, uint8_t *pin)
{
  uint8_t string[14];

  // ASCII string conversion
  sprintf((char *)(string), "%llu", number);

  // Pin verification
  if (memcmp(pin, string, 4))
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

I've been told that it works, but I'm trying to run this on a STM32 chip and the `sprintf` function doesn't work properly. I've tried solutions like using the `PRIu64` modifier from the `inttypes.h` library, but it still doesn't work.

I don't mind to change this function if there is a way to avoid the use of `sprintf`.

Thanks!

Comment: The format string should be `"%" PRIu64`.  But a uint64_t requires up to 20 digits (and a terminating `\0`), so you may be experiencing a buffer overrun because your string is of length 14 rather than 21. Can you provide a complete example, with the output you obtain rather than just noting it "doesn't work"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PaulHankin, I just added the code from the function. I don't know the details about the variable "number", but I've  just been told that it can be 14 digits long maximum.

Comment: Isn't there an `ltoa` function or something like that, that's more direct than interpreting a control string in `sprintf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> run this on a STM32 chip and the sprintf function doesn't work properly

You are using standard C library implementation (most probably `newlib` in it's "nano") version that does not support long long printf format specifiers.

Either:

- do not use long long format specifier and find other way
- provide your own library for printing long long numbers
- use a C standard library that supports long long printing

  - ie. use full newlib version, ie. remove `-specs=nano.specs` or `-lnano` from your compiler command line

Note that:

- `told that it can be 14 digits long maximum` then 14 byte buffer is too short to store a string with 14 digits.
- prefer `snprintf` to protect against buffer overflows

Comment: You are completely right. I changed the compiler configuration from -specs=nano.specs to "Standard C" and the function works perfectly now. Thanks for your help! I'll consider the ``snprintf`` function to avoid overflows.